# Scale Google maps Marker Image by Meters(fixed geographic size)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a svg file that I'm using it for the google map marker. The size is 65px x 65px.

I want to make sure this customized marker can be scaled to 1500 meters. It should zoom while the map is zoom.

I'm not sure how to make this work. Need a algorithm to calculate the scaledSize based on the zoom level and make user it is 1500 meters on the map.

```
            var offset = new google.maps.Point(50, 50);
            var getIcon = function (uid, selected) {
                return {
                    url: svg_url,
                    anchor: offset,
                    scaledSize: sccaledSize // not sure what to put here
                };
            };
            new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(xx,yy),
                    icon: getIcon(Uid, false)
                });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a [google.maps.Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle)?  Its radius is in meters.

Comment: The reason is circle doesn't works like a marker, circle can't be grouped doesn't support marker cluster

Comment: You might want to include those additional constraints in your question. Although I don't know why a circle "can't be grouped".

Comment: @geocodezip Also, google.maps.Circle is sometimes not perfectly round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/hDRO4oHVSeM) the following function could be utilized for calculating meters per pixel in Google Maps:

```
function getScale(latLng,zoom){
  return 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)
}
```

Hence the size of the icon could be specified like this:

```
 var zoom = map.getZoom();
 var scale = getScale(position,zoom + 1); //meters per pixel
 var width = 1500 / scale; 
 var height = width;

 var icon = {
    url: "https://openclipart.org/download/82549/blue-circle.svg",
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 50),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(width, height)
 };
```

**Complete example**

```js
var map;
var marker;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: { lat: 60.1823822, lng: 25.0036073 }
  });

 

  

 //var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
 //     center: map.getCenter(),
 //     radius: 1500,  //in meters
 //     map: map
 // });

 
  marker = createMarker(map.getCenter(),map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
     marker.setMap(null);
     marker = createMarker(marker.getPosition(),map);
   });

}


function createMarker(position,map) {
     var zoom = map.getZoom();
     var scale = getScale(position,zoom + 1); //meters per pixel
     var width = 1500 / scale; 
     var height = width;

     var icon = {
        url: "https://openclipart.org/download/82549/blue-circle.svg",
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 50),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(width, height)
     };

     return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon
     });
}


function getScale(latLng,zoom){
  return 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap&signed_in=true" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I found the google thread you linked before this answer. I wanted to get rid of the magic number "156543.03392", so I googled it and found myself here. Any insight as to what the heck that number is?